# What is the default protocol used for Indy TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL if not explicitly set?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

Greetings SO brain trust.

What is the default protocol used if no protocol is explicitly set for Indy 10 TIdSSLIOHanderSocketOpenSSL?

I ran across some code today where a protocol is not explicitly set.

```
  HTTPReq := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  IdSSLIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  if Assigned(HTTPReq) then begin
    HTTPReq.ReadTimeout := 180000;//set read timeout to 3 minutes
    HTTPReq.Request.ContentType := 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8';
    HTTPReq.Request.Accept := 'text/xml';
    HTTPReq.Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip,deflate';
    HTTPReq.HTTPOptions := [];
    HTTPReq.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandler;
  end;
```

Note there is no explicit setting for the protocol used! What is used by default if nothing is set? My concern is this is using TLS 1.0 or something that is rapidly being deprecated.

Using Delphi 10.2 Tokyo Update 1 and Indy 10.6.2.5366 and the latest 1.0.2n Open SLL DLLs

Cheers!

TJ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default is indeed TLS 1.0 only. You can see this by looking at the declarations of the `SSLOptions.Method` and `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` properties. They are both set to `sslvTLSv1`, as specified by the `DEF_SSLVERSION` and `DEF_SSLVERSIONS` constants in the `IdSSLOpenSSL` unit.

Comment: Thank you Remy! A quick aside - If TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 are both added as versions will the component attempt to negotiate  TLS 1.2 first and then TLS 1.1 if TLS 1.2 does not work?

Comment: No. OpenSSL will send a single handshake that specifies TLS 1.0 is the lowest supported version and TLS 1.2 is the highest supported version.  The other party will then decide which specific version to continue handshaking with. If that negotiation fails, the connection is dropped and an error is raised. Indy will not retry other versions automatically (that is a todo item in Indy's code), you would have handle that manually in your own code.

Comment: OK, if I set a Method ofsslvSSLv23 and SSLVersions of [sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2] only then will it specify it supports TLS 1.1 lowest and TLS 1.2 highest and then the server can pick which option to use? (I'm a client in this scenario) If not TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 I don't want a connection to be established.

Comment: You do not need to set the `Method`, only the `SSLVersions` (they are mutually exclusive, setting one sets the other). But yes, that is basically how it works.

Comment: Thank you! One other quick question if you don't mind. Should `.Mode` be `sslmClient`, `sslmBoth`, or `sslmUnassigned`? I cannot find a clear reference to what this does.

Comment: In your case, it should be `sslmClient`, since you are not running a server. But `sslmBoth` will also work. If it is set to `sslmUnassigned`, it will get set to `sslmClient` automatically when connecting to the HTTPS server.